# Flash like animation editing and container format for OpenGL environment?

Tags: iphone, animation, opengl-es, collada

Are there ANY tools that lets an animator / designer create scripted animations that can export to an OpenGL compatible format -- that are similar to the timeline editing in Flash or After Effects?

Does OpenGL ES have some kind of animation playback or container format? ( is there something similar to .swf for OpenGL? )

Im looking for something that lets a designer / animator do his work with a timeline and in a traditional animation environment... meanwhile still having integration with OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

No. The closest thing, to my (albeit limited) knowledge of the subject is as follows:

`Flash CS5. -> Export to iPhone. -> Rejection By Apple.`

I wish there was.

EDIT:

Seriously though...

OpenGL is a low level software layer that is supposed to be hardware independent. It can map textures on polygons. There are some game frameworks that do abstract some of the work. cocos2d, SIO2 etc. But those still require lots of programming.

Comment: You could have mentioned Collada? ;)

This does much of what Im asking... however Im still not sure how Collada handles animation.  Specifically can I can a number of animations even for one object and have those run from the game engine.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: tbarbe - I said `No ... to my albeit limitd knowledge.` You seem to know more than me. Why the question then?